# box-shadow order of parameters

Tags: css

From https://github.com/orderedlist/minimal/blob/master/stylesheets/styles.css :

```
box-shadow:inset #fff 0 1px 0, inset rgba(0,0,0,0.03) 0 -1px 0;
```

From http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-shadow.asp :

```
box-shadow: h-shadow v-shadow blur spread color inset;
```

So among other things the ordering seems to be a little different. In the github.com example inset is first whereas w3schools.com has it as being last. Does the order not matter or something? Or maybe it doesn't matter for those attributes that can be disambiguated from others?

I guess 0 is the h-shadow, 1px the v-shadow and the last 0 the blur?

Comment: CSS is weird. Just try and use them in the order that you most commonly see them used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, only parameters of the same type have a fixed order. `h-shadow`, `v-shadow`, `blur` and `spread` therefore must appear in this order (and you can only omit from the end), but `inset` and `colour` can be placed anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

Normally,the parameters of 
box-shadow
are in the order of 
`horizontal-offset`
`vertical-offset`
`blur`
`spread`
`color`
and  `inset`.
Out of these,you can place 
`inset`
and
`color`
anywhere in the list.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you can put `inset` at the end or last (but the order of everything else like horizontal shadow, vertical shadow, blur, spread and color does matter. As you can see in the [w3c specs](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-background/#the-box-shadow) they show `inset?` at the start in the syntax while in the examples you find them being used at the end.